# TNSNAMES.ORA file is missing even after installing ODP.NET from oracle website

Tags: .net, entity-framework, odp.net, tnsnames

I am trying to create a new connection for an Entity Data Model, from Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I keep getting error

> ora-12154: tns:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Though I have installed ODP.NET by running ODTforVS2019_193100.vsix but I still  don't see `TNSNAMES.ORA` created in my `C:\Users\harafat\Oracle\network\admin folder`

Comment: this is managed. Drop tns.ora into your bin folder. Or just do without it. Your connections string should contain `data source=Server_Name:1521/yourSID`

Comment: the link you supplied was invalid. You can't follow Oracle download link without being logged on. These direct links don't work